# Correcting to the correct URL

Tags: python, json, regex, python-2.7

I have written a simple script to access JSON to get the keywords needed to be used for the URL.

Below is the script that I have written:

```
import urllib2
import json

f1 = open('CatList.text', 'r')
f2 = open('SubList.text', 'w')
lines = f1.read().splitlines()


for  line in lines:

    url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle='+line+'&cmlimit=100'
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(json_obj)
    for item in data['query']:
            for i in data['query']['categorymembers']:
                print i['title']
                print '-----------------------------------------'
                f2.write((i['title']).encode('utf8')+"\n")
```

In this script, the program will first read CatList which provides a list of keywords used for the URL.

Here is a sample of what the CatList.text contains.

```
Category:Branches of geography
Category:Geography by place
Category:Geography awards and competitions
Category:Geography conferences
Category:Geography education
Category:Environmental studies
Category:Exploration
Category:Geocodes
Category:Geographers
Category:Geographical zones
Category:Geopolitical corridors
Category:History of geography
Category:Land systems
Category:Landscape
Category:Geography-related lists
Category:Lists of countries by geography
Category:Navigation
Category:Geography organizations
Category:Places
Category:Geographical regions
Category:Surveying
Category:Geographical technology
Category:Geography terminology
Category:Works about geography
Category:Geographic images
Category:Geography stubs
```

My program get the keywords and placed it in the URL.

However I am not able to get the result.I have checked the code by printing the URL:

```
import urllib2
import json

f1 = open('CatList.text', 'r')
f2 = open('SubList2.text', 'w')
lines = f1.read().splitlines()


for  line in lines:

    url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle='+line+'&cmlimit=100'
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(json_obj)


    f2.write(url+'\n')
```

The result I get is as follows in sublist2:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Branches of geography&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography by place&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography awards and competitions&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography conferences&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography education&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Environmental studies&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Exploration&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geocodes&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geographers&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geographical zones&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geopolitical corridors&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:History of geography&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Land systems&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Landscape&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography-related lists&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Lists of countries by geography&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Navigation&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography organizations&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Places&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geographical regions&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Surveying&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geographical technology&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography terminology&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Works about geography&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geographic images&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography stubs&cmlimit=100
```

It shows that the URL is placed correctly.

But when I run the full code it was not able to get the correct result.

One thing I notice is when I place in the link to the address bar for example:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Branches of geography&cmlimit=100
```

It gives the correct result because the address bar auto corrects it to :

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Branches%20of%20geography&cmlimit=100
```

I believe that if %20 is added in place of an empty space between the word " Category: Branches of Geography" , my script will be able to get the correct JSON items.

**Problem**:
But I am not sure how to modify this statement in the above code to get the replace the blank spaces that is contained in CatList  with %20.

Please forgive me for the bad formatting and the long post, I am still trying to learn python.

Thank you for helping me.

**Edit:**

Thank you Tim.  Your solution works:

```
 url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle='+urllib2.quote(line)+'&cmlimit=100'
```

It was able to print the correct result:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3ABranches%20of%20geography&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeography%20by%20place&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeography%20awards%20and%20competitions&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeography%20conferences&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeography%20education&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AEnvironmental%20studies&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AExploration&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeocodes&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeographers&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeographical%20zones&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeopolitical%20corridors&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AHistory%20of%20geography&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3ALand%20systems&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3ALandscape&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeography-related%20lists&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3ALists%20of%20countries%20by%20geography&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3ANavigation&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeography%20organizations&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3APlaces&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeographical%20regions&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3ASurveying&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeographical%20technology&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeography%20terminology&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AWorks%20about%20geography&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeographic%20images&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AGeography%20stubs&cmlimit=100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `urllib.quote()` to replace special characters in an url:

Python 2:

```
import urllib
line = 'Category:Branches of geography'
url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=' + urllib.quote(line) + '&cmlimit=100'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote

Python 3:

```
import urllib.parse
line = 'Category:Branches of geography'
url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=' + urllib.parse.quote(line) + '&cmlimit=100'
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply , may I have an example on how to use it please?

Comment: I have tried import urllib .  I then replace "url_add = wiki url " , followed by " url = urllib.quote(url_add) " , and followed by " json_obj = urllib.urlopen(url) "  and lastly " data = json.load(json_obj) "  but it wasn't working.

Comment: The error message I get is No such file or directory: : 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Branches of geography&cmlimit=100'

Comment: Hi Tim , I have posted my result in my post. I wasn't able to get the correct url :(

Comment: @windboy Have you tried to run the three lines of example code from above? They can be run standalone in in the python shell and result in the desired url format.

Comment: Yes Tim, I ran it and  the result is shown in my post.  For example: "https%3A//en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php%3Faction%3Dquery%26format%3Djson%26list%3Dcategorymembers%26cmtitle%3DCategory%3ABranches%20of%20geography%26cmlimit%3D100".

Comment: The code works fine but it wasnt able to give me to correct url.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Just quote the argument.

Comment: Thank you very much tim. I really appreciate your help.